# excel function to get value of another cell

Tags: excel, worksheet-function

[Image describing the problem http://img215.imageshack.us/img215/3725/20100314235127schedule2.jpg](http://img215.imageshack.us/img215/3725/20100314235127schedule2.jpg)

I hope the [image above](http://img215.imageshack.us/img215/3725/20100314235127schedule2.jpg) can explain what I need. :)

Problem 1: Get the date where it is the first value in the row

Problem 2: Get the date where the value is 100

I would also attach the actual excel file,
but I am limited to posting only 1 link.

Comment: @geff_chang: Can you add the link to the document as comment?

Comment: I guess this will only work with a vba function (should be fine as you tagged the question with `vba`). How will the function know which cells have to be filled? Are you going to configure that or is there another way to find out?

Comment: @Peter Lang: the 4th row of each group (those under the dates) is to be filled up with values from 1 to 100. The cells shaded in blue should be calculated.

Comment: @Peter Lang: Although it's rather late, here's the document: http://rapidshare.com/files/365469750/schedule.rar

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Function for left blue cell:

> =IF(COUNTIF(L11:BJ11,">0"),INDEX($L$2:$BJ$2,MATCH(TRUE,INDEX(L11:BJ11>0,0),0)),"")

Function for right blue cell:

> =IF(COUNTIF(L11:BJ11,100),INDEX($L$2:$BJ$2,MATCH(100,L11:BJ11,0)),"")