# Get value from a row that corresponds (in the same column) to a cell in another row

Tags: excel

This is related to: [excel function to get value of another cell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2442808/excel-function-to-get-value-of-another-cell)
(but slightly different)

I want to get the date (on Row D), that corresponds
to the last non-blank value in another row.
See below for what I am trying to describe.

```
  | D2  | D3  | D4  | D5   <- Dates
-------------------------
A | X2  | X3* | X4* | X5   <- A should get D4, X4 is the last non-blank value
B | Y2* | Y3* | Y4* | Y5*  <- B should get D5, Y5 is the last non-blank value
```

Asterisk (*) denotes a non-blank cell/value.

Can somebody please help me with the formula? Thanks.

[image]

Comment: I guess "should get D5, Y4 is the last non-blank value" should be "should get D5, Y5 is the last non-blank value". Right?

Comment: @shahkalpesh: You're correct: should get D5, Y5 is the last non-blank value. I'll change my post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this in $E$7. It's an array formula, so you have to hit ctrl+shift+enter.

=INDEX($A$2:$AF$2,1,MAX(IF(ISBLANK(L7:AF7),0,COLUMN(L7:AF7))))

If that works, you can copy and paste it to $E$11 and $E$15.

Comment: Thanks, it works! But, can you make it handle cases where there are no entries in the row? For this case, can you make it blank?

Comment: Hi, I found a formula, but if you can suggest a more efficient formula, please advise. =IF(COUNTA(L15:AF15)>0, INDEX($A$2:$AF$2,1,MAX(IF(ISBLANK(L15:AF15),1,COLUMN(L15:AF15)))), "")

Comment: That's probably what I would've done, but if you really want a more efficient formula and K2 is always going to be blank, you could set it to ' or ="" and change the formula to =INDEX($A$2:$AF$2,1,MAX(IF(ISBLANK(K7:AF7),11,COLUMN(K7:AF7))))

Answer (score 0):

Formula in cell A1 `=OFFSET(B1, 0, COUNTA(B1:F1) - 1)`
Formula in cell A2 `=OFFSET(B2, 0, COUNTA(B2:F2) - 1)`

[image: Example screenshot]

Comment: @shahkalpesh: Hi, the document has 3 rows. The first row is dates. The rows after that are data. The first column should contain the date when the last non-blank data is.

Comment: @geff: Can you explain the question, with the help of a screenshot?

Comment: @shahkalpesh: Please check my question; I added an image.

Comment: @geff: In cell E7, you could write `=OFFSET(T7, (-1 * ROW()) + 1, COUNTA(T7:Z7) - 1)`. Does this work?

Comment: @shahkalpesh: No, the value returned was 1/3. Expected value should be 3/10.

Comment: @geff: Is it possible for you to share the file (with dummy data) for me to look into the reason why formula I gave, isnt working?

Comment: See if this formula `=OFFSET(T7, (-1 * ROW()) + 2, COUNTA(T7:Z7) - 1)` works for cell E7.